# Setting asp.net text box value using jquery with ajaxcontroltoolkit watermark

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watermark

I am using asp.net textboxes with ajaxcontroltoolkit watermark control. There is a list box with entries that can be edited using the text boxes. On selection change of the list box I need to set the text in the text box. I am using jQuery for this purpose.

Three predefined values are added in the list box. There are two scenarios -
1. When an entry is added manually using the text boxes, the text appears properly in text box
2. But if any predefined entry is selected without adding any manual entry, the text appears in the text box but only as a watermark and is not editable.

Here is the code -

```
... some controls here
<asp:TextBox ID="ebSectionEnglish" runat="server" CssClass="BasicTextBox" Width="215px" />                                
<act:TextBoxWatermarkExtender WatermarkCssClass="TextBoxWatermark"
     ID="tbwSectionEnglish" runat="server" TargetControlID="ebSectionEnglish"
     WatermarkText="English" />
<asp:ListBox ID="lbSection" runat="server" Width="215px" Rows="6"></asp:ListBox>
... some more tags

// script code
var selItem = jQuery('[id$=lbSection] option:selected');
if (selItem == null)
   return false;
jQuery('[id$=ebSectionEnglish]').val(selItem.val());
... some more script
```

I am using jQuery 1.5. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to set text: `$find("<%= tbwSectionEnglish.ClientID %>").set_text(value);`

Comment: Thanks for the response but this would set the text of the watermark control. I need to set the text of the textbox. The weird thing about my code is that the textbox text is set but it appears like a watermark.

Comment: @RohitSahasrabudhe just try it

Comment: Funny, because this script works well on Watermark demo page from console: `$find("ctl00_SampleContent_TextBoxWatermarkExtender1").set_Text("Hello, watermark"); alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_SampleContent_TextBox1").value)`

Comment: this is demo page: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

Comment: Yuriy, This works ! There was a typo when I tried it first time. Thx a ton :) Just one query though - how does the $ sign work when we are using both jQuery and ACT ?

Comment: @RohitSahasrabudhe since `$` and `$get`, `$find` considered as different names they aren't interfered with each other